# Auto numbering in a column for the same values and restart again when a different value is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with thousands of data. I have two columns called *name* and *values*.

I want to add another column that is going to be like bullets numbering of the names. In my case some names are repeated but with different values. Let me show you an example:

```
value | name    | result
1     | item001 | .05
2     | item001 | 1.5
3     | item001 | 3.5
1     | item025 | 5.5
1     | item028 | 6.5
1     | item020 | 7.0
2     | item020 | 8.6
3     | item020 | 10.2
4     | item020 | 21.1
```

So as you can see I need numbering to the name column that has the same value.

Comment: Have you try Jerry's formula ? .. or you need VBA ?

Comment: I stared 5 minutes on your numbers - and I still don't see the algorithm

Comment: Same here. Explain better how result is calculated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this formula for the numbering, if that's what you're looking for, assuming that the first `item001`: is in cell `B2`:

```
=IF(B2=B1, A1+1, 1)
```

And drag the formula down to the bottom.

So basically, if the cells B2 and B1 are the same, add one to the previous numbering, otherwise, start anew to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula:

```
=COUNT(  FILTER($A$2:A2,  $B$2:B2=B2))
```

It doesn't `SPILL` so you enter it in the first row (adjust references as needed), then Copy and Paste down the column.

`FILTER()` creates an array inside the formula of all the entries in the `value` column above the current cell plus the current cell itself for which the `name` cells for them match the current row's `name` cell.

`COUNT()` then counts those up and that is the entry for the `value` column.

The thing that makes it work is creating the listing of cells ABOVE, and including, the current cell. That is done using a range of the first cell in the column, let's say "A2" here, using absolute addressing for it (`$A$2` rather than `A2`) so the start of the range is fixed in place, and relative referencing for the right half of the range so that it changes as one goes down the column thereby expanding the range. So `$A$2:A2` becomes `$A$2:A34` in row 34.

Doing that keeps the data below the current row from influencing the count.